# nested list/dictionary comprehensions how to add a missing element

Tags: python, nested, nltk

i need to add a weather string to my output how would i do this?

```py
weather_data_train = list()

for j in range(0,len(weather_sents_train)):
    weather_tokens = weather_sents_train[j].split()
    weather_dict = {}
    for key in weather_tokens:
        weather_dict[key] = True
    weather_data_train.append(weather_dict)
```

Output i am getting

```py
[{'today': True, 'it': True, 'is': True, 'raining': True}, 
{'looking': True, 'cloudy': True, 'today': True}, 
{'it': True, 'is': True, 'nice': True, 'weather': True}]
```

output that i want to get

```py
[({'today': True, 'it': True, 'is': True, 'raining': True}, 'weather'),
({'looking': True, 'cloudy': True, 'today': True}, 'weather'),
({'it': True, 'is': True, 'nice': True, 'weather': True}, 'weather')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enclose the dict in a tuple with `'weather'` as the second item.

Change:

```
weather_data_train.append(weather_dict)
```

to:

```
weather_data_train.append((weather_dict, 'weather'))
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite the code with a list comprehension:

```
weather_data_train = [(dict.fromkeys(s.split(), True), 'weather') for s in weather_sents_train]
```